# INDIA - Are last minute tickets cheaper at airline ticket counter vs online?

Tags: tickets, india, airlines, price

I'll be coming by road and I'm unsure of my arrival time at the airport, at least till a couple of days before the date.

The departure and arrival airports are well connected through multiple airlines and multiple flights, and I have flexibility regarding the time of departure.

Is it better to scour the booking counters of multiple airlines for a **great deal on last minute** departures, rather than booking something like 24 hours before ?

*I'm asking for India specifically, but any help is appreciated.*

Comment: Related: *[Last minute flight bookings - better to book online or at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4213)*; also see *[Cheap last minute flight from Toronto to Ottawa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85558/)* and others like it, and more generally, *[How do airlines determine ticket prices?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49417/1480)*

Comment: Why would it be cheaper offline? Almost nothing is cheaper offline these days.

Comment: @JonathanReez It could be cheaper if online booking has stopped, the plane is still not full and the person flying would pay something, so any extra that the airline gets would be a plus, since they are flying the aircraft anyway. Thus there exists an incentive for cheap last minute tickets. Just wanted to see if people have experienced it often enough

Comment: This would encourage people to camp out at the airport, rather than buying tickets on time.

Comment: @JonathanReez Possible, but I'm not envisaging a very cheap ticket, maybe a bit lesser than what it was a day or 2 back, and maybe only for a single ticket or at max for a couple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The ticket desk can sell a few things that the websites cannot (most notably complicated itineraries) but for a simple one way or return flight, they access the same fare tariffs.

You usually pay a handling fee now to purchase a ticket in person at an airport ticket desk, on top of the normal fare.

Therefore it is almost always better to buy online.